# Obtener imagen desde un servidor por Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imagen, get

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$.ajax({
     url: urls,
     type: "GET",
     beforeSend: function(req) {
      req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
    }
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

hago un get a una imagen en un servidor y cuando recibo la respuesta obtengo más o menos lo siguiente(claro más grande pero no pondré todo, solo un fragmento):

```
 �w�9��c�^�u�l��>,�F��{c�Y2����r������F�.���LO��S���?�E�G�f�K=���<�=ۉ������Qa�W�?)/wp�e'"?HkGd�bK#�Z�ʋt4���q�
 7KI�ҙyohdD�T���ń�Py'躳��k�/s��=�Yq+�c$��}�!��0��i�����XH."�&ԙ�,��rSsF��@�2@q#��
 ��
```

o sea me está devolviendo toda esta data pero con caracteres que no reconoce o yo misma no reconozco, como podría solucionar esto y que me traiga los datos de manera correcta, porque quiero a la imagen que traigo pasarla a binario con un método que lo hace pero estos caracteres raros hacen que la imagen se pierda.

Comment: Ahora no puedo extenderme, pero si quieres ir investigando te recomiendo que busques como enviarla en Base 64. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: Aparentemente la imagen ya está en binario. ¿La sirves tu misma? Si es así, sugiero que incluyas el código con el que la sirves. Por otro lado sugiero que indiques qué quieres hacer con ella, pues es obvio que no quieres verla en la consola, ¿o si?

Comment: Ah, y bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: te sugiero revisar lo siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354638/ajax-to-get-image-from-remote-server